# How to fix the problem with reading text files of a list of files from a folder for creating rows of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to export the data from the text files into a dataframe in pandas. I have created a list of those files from the specific path of the folder. For 2 or 3 times the code worked just fine. I have become able to export from text files into dataframe. But sometimes later it showed some error that is **FileNotFoundError**. 'link1.txt' is the first file from the desired folder.

```
path = "F:/study/folder0/"
dir_list = os.listdir(path) #list of the files in folder
length = len(dir_list) 
for i in range(length): 
    text = pd.read_csv(dir_list[i], sep = " ", header = None)
    text['new'] = text.apply(' '.join, axis=1)
```

The error that I have got

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'link1.txt' does not exist: b'link1.txt'
```

Comment: Without knowing the structure of the files in path folder it is hard to understand what you want to achieve. For each file a text dataframe will be made consisting of as many columns as there are words in the file and then a new column 'new' will be created having a string with all words joined. On the next loop this dataframe text object will be replaced with the content of the next file, etc. Do you want it appended instead? In which case there must be some relation between the files to make it consistent. Can yo explain a bit

Comment: The files are normal text files which have some long sentences of newspaper articles. Yes, I want 'new' column to work as you said. I dont want replacement to be happened in the next loop. I haven't added further lines of my code but as you said I want the next text file to be added into the next row of the dataframe for the future loop. All the files are exactly the same type in the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File not found mainly happens because the path you have provided is wrong or the file doesn't actually exist.

When you are doing `pd.read_csv(dir_list[i], sep = " ", header = None)`
you are giving each file/folder name rather than the path of the file. so in your current directory where you are writing the python code the file doesn't exist

One solution to this is appending path with each each element of dir list

```
path= r"c:\somedir\somefolder\"
dir_list2=[]
for x in range(length):
    dir_list2.append(path+str(dir_list[x]))
```

The problem for you here would be the path you have taken has forward slash(/) while windows uses backword slashes for navigating.
Use this solution for your answer

```
path = "F:/study/folder0/"
dir_list = os.listdir(path) #list of the files in folder
length = len(dir_list) 
for i in range(length): 
    text = pd.read_csv("F:\\study\\folder0\\"+str(dir_list[i]), sep = " ", header = None)
    text['new'] = text.apply(' '.join, axis=1)
```

Thank you, hoped it helped.

Comment: First solution seems a bit difficult for me. May I know how should I define dir_list at first? But I have tried the 2nd solution and it worked just fine

Comment: same way you did in your solution.Created a second list and appended the path to each element of dir_list, so when using pd.read_csv("F:\\study\\folder0\\"+str(dir_list[i]), sep = " ", header = None) instead use pd.read_csv(dir_list2[i], sep = " ", header = None) while traversing the dir_list2.